# What master's degree is recommended to study at a university for establishing a start-up after learning computer science?

Tags: education, learning, masters, computer-science

I studied for 3 years computer science at a relatively good university, and at the same time I have several years of experience with broad and deep knowledge in many fields on the subject. I am a creative person and I am interested in expressing my Innovative ideas by setting up a start-up from scratch which will bring a technological solution to many companies in high-tech.

I wanted to ask in general what it is recommended to study for a master's degree so that I can bring the product that I can build independently through my knowledge of computer science and experience to a successful start-up company?

Comment: Maybe just buy this book https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74B3suAcW_o and use your tuition money you were going to spend on an MBA to start your first business instead.

Comment: A startup is very much about your product idea and your marketing/management skills. Computer skills are ranking second at best.

Comment: First and foremost to understand step by step how to establish an start-up company from scratch and make it accessible to the market.
What I mean by that, I want to learn the other side of the business of company, there is a product In one side, and In the other side the  marketing/management skills and finance models how to bring the company to success.

Comment: (1) JayZ's answer below (2) if you are studying in the US, you can take the path of the SBIR or DARPA grant, in which case you want to do a PhD and pick an adviser whose work coincides with the tech you are into, and ideally one who has sat on grant review boards in the past. (3) seek out "incubator" type places and ask this question to them

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/166311/705

Answer (score 6):

None.

Building a succesful startup is not much related to the arcanes of computer science. It's much more related to sheer [determination](http://www.paulgraham.com/determination.html), ability to overcome most problems, both on the technical and business side. It's also realted to the ability to adapt your initial [idea](https://www.reddit.com/r/startups/comments/2izghj/ideas_are_worthless_execution_is_everything/) to the specifics of the market.

Comment: "It's much more related to sheer determination, ability to overcome most problems, both on the technical and business side. It's also related to the ability to adapt your initial idea to the specifics of the market." - and all of that, there isn't a degree that can give me a good basis for this principles?

Comment: No, there is no such degree.

Comment: There is, it's called Degree of 'Hard Knocks". Anybody would is qualified teach this degree wouldn't be in the academic setting teaching it... they'll be using it and honing it according to business demands, and that's what makes them qualified.

Comment: To be clear, while ability to adapt can be somewhat learned (but it's already very late once you're a student), determination is a given. There is no lever on it. Most people - including myself - don't have enough of it to succesfully launch a startup. Hence @Nelson 's excellent comment.

Comment: @Nelson - I have seen successful business owners teach a college course.

Answer (score 5):

Look for a business school with rich students, heirs of successful/powerful corporations and a strong alumni network.

Your goal won't be your diploma (just enough work to get it) but mainly to create connections with a lot of people.

After school you want a good network of people to recommend your business to the right people or maybe even invest in your business.

Comment: But which field to learn in the business school do you recommend for my goal?

Comment: @Yakir Whatever that you're capable of completing without struggling. Your goal there is to network with people. You obviously didn't understand this answer because it's really not about the degree. If you're studying 10 hours a day to complete the degree, you are making exactly 0 connections with people and "failed".

Answer (score 3):

**What you need for your startup to succeed (in order of importance):**

1. **viable idea**
2. **LUCK!**
3. **connections/investors (money)**
4. **Perseverance and a dollop of common sense**
5. **a skill in business management (for which you don't need a degree)**
6. secondary concerns (people who will implement the idea,....)

Only the business management degree can be obtained at university, the rest is independent of education.

The only thing you have right now is the last point (secondary concerns)...

Answer (score 1):

In the US, Lehigh University has a [Master's In Technical Entrepreneurship](https://te.lehigh.edu/) .  You may want to search for a similar program at a university near you.

Answer (score 1):

I went for a Masters in Industrial Engineering (the engineering equivalent to an MBA). I had many years of technical programming. I took some of the first classes offered on entrepreneurship in this country.

None of that made a difference when I started a company.

There are so many skills needed to start a company that cannot be taught in school. The number one skill that is needed is to be able to do the critical marketing to identify what can be sold to whom at what price. Since the answer to that changes month to month and depends on your own character and situation, no class could ever give you that answer.

The point about networking in college is to find the connections that can provide you with the money to start, the initial sales to start, and the people you will need to hire to start. It can be a lot harder to find those outside of a college, but it can be done.

The best way to start a company is to go out and find a customer for what you want to sell and then build it for them.